# add a custom disable input on component not working in angular

Tags: angular

I have a component in angular which contain a button.

I have set the component to get an input name disabled like this :

```
export class ConfirmationButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() icon: string;
  @Input() tooltip: string;
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
```

I call it like this :

```
  <app-confirmation-button 
    [icon]="'select-all'"
    disabled="missions.length === 0"
    tooltip="{{ 'BUTTON.DELETE_ALL' | translate}}"
```

but this return me

```
 console.log(this.disabled) // "missions.length === 0"
```

I then tried the other way so

```
  <app-confirmation-button 
    [icon]="'select-all'"
    disabled="{{missions.length === 0}}"
    tooltip="{{ 'BUTTON.DELETE_ALL' | translate}}"
```

but this return me

```
 console.log(this.disabled) // "true"
```

so a string and not a boolean...

How do I get a boolean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I fixed using `[disabled]` will read about binding with `[` and without